# Jetpack Compose "onSurface" Color not working

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm testing with Material Theming with Jetpack Compose and I'm not sure why I can't make the theme's `onSurface` color work.

Here is the `Theme.kt` with a `onSurface` color set to `Color.Red`:

```
private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = Purple200,
    primaryVariant = Purple700,
    secondary = Teal200,
    onSurface = Color.Red, // <------- HERE
    onPrimary = Color.Blue, // <----- HERE
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Purple500,
    primaryVariant = Purple700,
    secondary = Teal200,
    onSurface = Color.Red, // <------- AND HERE
    onPrimary = Color.Blue, // <----- HERE
)

@Composable
fun ExploringMaterialTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

and here is the Activity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp()
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    ExploringMaterialTheme {
        // I also tried
        // Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface) {
        Surface {
            Text(text = "Hello!!", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting "Hello!!" to be shown in Red, but instead, it's shown in normal black. Any ideas what I'm missing?

[image: result]

It works has expected when I set the a color in `Surface` component. `Surface` gets the right `on` Color (the `onPrimary` in this case):

```
        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary) {
            Text(text = "Hello!!", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
        }
```

[image: result2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Surface` composable uses:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentColor provides contentColor){
            //
            content()
}
```

where the `contentColor` is defined by:

```
fun Colors.contentColorFor(backgroundColor: Color): Color {
    return when (backgroundColor) {
    primary -> onPrimary
    primaryVariant -> onPrimary
    secondary -> onSecondary
    secondaryVariant -> onSecondary
    background -> onBackground
    surface -> onSurface
    error -> onError
    else -> Color.Unspecified
    }
}
```

Currently you have to specify the **`surface`** color in your theme:

```
private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Blue500,
    surface = Color.Yellow)
```

In this case the `Text` uses the `onSurface` color.

If you don't specify the `surface` color the `Surface` components use the `background` as colorBackground and the `onBackground` for the `Text`.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some issue where the color matches the background color instead of the surface color, so it returns the `onBackground`. If you set your `surface` color so that it is different from the `background` color then it will pick the correct `onSurface` color, for insance

```
private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = Purple200,
    primaryVariant = Purple700,
    secondary = Teal200,
    onSurface = Color.Red,
    surface = Color.Green,
)
```

This may be a bug in compose.

This happens here:

```
fun Colors.contentColorFor(backgroundColor: Color): Color {
    return when (backgroundColor) {
    primary -> onPrimary
    primaryVariant -> onPrimary
    secondary -> onSecondary
    secondaryVariant -> onSecondary
    background -> onBackground
    surface -> onSurface
    error -> onError
    else -> Color.Unspecified
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Francesc! You're right; we have to set a different color to `surface`. I accepted Grabriele's answer because he answered first. But really appreciated the help 